# Can you have two background services in your Android app running at the same time?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-service, android-background

I have two services in my App that do different things on the device. I might need to run the second one while the first one is running in the background. I am just wondering if that might create an issue on some Android versions?

Comment: The only problem I can think of is that services use the same memory resources as your activities, so it may be the case that they are too cpu-intensive which will hinder the performance of you app, but that seems farfetched.

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfectly acceptable use case.  Each instance of a `Service` is a separate object, running within your app's process.  Do note, however, that a `Service`'s callbacks (`onStartCommand()`, `onBind()`, etc.) are all run in the context of the *main thread* of your application.  You'll need to follow the best practices and guidelines for using background threads to do work in order to not starve off the other `Service` or any `Activity` which is active.